# По какому принципу выбрать опорный пункт в быстрой сортировке?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

По какому принципу выбирается опорный элемент в быстрой сортировке:

1. По принципу среднего числа
2. По принципу случайного числа?

Comment: Только не пытайтесь перебирать и искать среднее значение — потеряете скорость... А так — по большому счету — всегда существует такая расстановка, которая даст O(N²). Хотя, конечно, при случайном выборе это труднее.

Comment: Как угодно выбирается. Под средним числом обычно имеют в виду медиану из трёх чисел из подмассива.

Comment: Выбирайте как угодно, но осторожно. Например при выборе первого или последнего элемента массива сортировка отсортированного станет квадратичной. А это плохо.